# Slideshow per post Wordpress plugin in Loop.php for Grid View?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gridview, slideshow

I trying to find a Wordpress plugin that does slideshow of each post for grid-view websites.

On the homepage, if I highlight a picture (of that post) on the grid, it should do a slideshow of the gallery of that post.

I had a hard time typing in these keywords on search. And if no such plugin, how to do this via hardcode?

Thanks.

EDIT -- Found example, http://blog.bitique.co.uk/ ; is there a plugin for this? or how would I code this PHP in the LOOP.php?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about a wordpress plugin, but there are several jQuery plugins to do so in one way or another , and that are easy to implement..

http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/demo/3/

http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

Or you can just look at the source code of the website to learn how they did it ...